# convert sql query to entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

Please i need someone to help convert this query entity(c#) form.

```
select * 
from incident 
where Details like'%Help%' 
and status = 'Resolved' 
or details like '%Help%' and Status = 'Closed'
```

See what I tried

```
incident = incident.Where(s => s.Details.ToUpper().Contains(SearchParam.ToUpper()));
```

Comment: Are you 100% clear on which conditions of your `WHERE` clause (in your SQL statement) get combined how? I have a feeling you might want something else than what you *really* get right now...

Comment: Incidentally, you're looking to express this query in LINQ.  EF is just your persistence framework.  Have you looked into LINQPad?

Comment: Why isn't your query `WHERE Details LIKE '%Help%' AND [status] IN ('Resolved', 'Closed');`? Mixing `AND` and `OR` can be quite confusing, and repeating the same clause multiple times is wasteful. IMHO.

Comment: What i want is a query that will extract all closed and resolved incident from the incident table based on the input criterial provided by the user.  the input is the detail field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
incident = incident.Where(s => s.Details.ToUpper().Contains(SearchParam.ToUpper()) 
              && (s.Status == "Resolved" || s.Status == "Closed"));
```